# How to use Release Definition REST API for VSTS?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, devops, ms-release-management, azure-devops-rest-api

I have been successfully able to use Release Definition API on our TFS 2015 Update 3 on prem instance using API Version "3.0-preview.1". But ever since I started testing this on VSTS, I am continuously getting a 404 error stating

`Page not found` And a long block of HTML.

I am using PowerShell to call the API. And I am creating the API request as mentioned in the documentation using Personal Access Token and Alternate credential method.

`https://fabfiber.vsrm.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ff213d65-d61d-447c-b39d-d16f21b18364/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=3.0-preview.1`

Can someone let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: which URL are you actually using? You should replace 'fabfiber' with your VSTS account name, and the GUID with your own Team Project ID or Name

Comment: I have my own URL created in a similar manner stated above i.e. `https://<myinstance.visualstudio.com>/DefaultCollection/<Project ID>/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=3.0-preview.1`

Comment: then you are missing **.vsrm.** from the url, like `<myinstance>.vsrm.visualstudio.com` , as [documented](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/overview)

Comment: Thanks.. I got it. But I wonder why they have a different url for Release definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$vstsAccount = "[your vsts name]"
$user = "test"
$accessToken="[personal access token]"
$teamProject="[team project name]"
Function QueryWorkItem{
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$accessToken)))
 $uri="https://$vstsAccount.vsrm.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/$teamProject/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=3.0-preview.1"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}
```

Comment: Addition of vsrm worked. But can you explain me the reason for adding this and is there any documentation around this?

Comment: Also, is this only applicable to Release Management API?

Comment: I got the documentation reference. I somehow missed it. Never expected to be different from the other APIs.

Comment: @AnkushGupta Just refer to Rest API document (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/definitions), the format is https://{account}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version={version}[&$expand={enum}]

Answer (score -1):

You may refer the blog :-

1. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chandananjani/2016/04/15/using-releasemanagement-rest-apis/
2. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chandananjani/2016/04/27/using-releasehttpclient-for-interacting-with-releasemanagement-service/
   as well to know as how to use the release management REST API's.

Comment: Links are broken